# Cannot access app engine application from LAN

Tags: linux, google-app-engine

I added the `--address=0.0.0.0` to GAE arguments in eclipse.
From the same machine I can access the server with:

- `http://192.168.1.7:8888/createUser.html`
- `http://localhost:8888/createUser.html`
- `http://0.0.0.0:8888/createUser.html`
- `http://127.0.0.1:8888/createUser.html`

However if I try to access it from an Android device on the same LAN through `http://192.168.1.7:8888/createUser.html` I get an *"Oops!"*.

The Android device can ping `192.168.1.7` and vice versa.

I'm using Linux and I don't have any firewall. What's the solution?

Thank you.

EDIT: I also tried to access the page from another PC in the same LAN but didn't work. I also tested the port using telnet: it works from the machine but doesn't work from other devices in the same LAN.

Comment: Do you have the INTERNET permission enabled in your manifest?

Comment: @Byron Do you mean somewhere in App Engine?

Comment: No in your android app.

Comment: @Byron I'm simply using Chrome on the Android device to access the .html page.

Comment: Sorry, thought this was an app question. Can you access that url from another machine as apposed to a phone?

Comment: @Byron I tried from another PC and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to open the port 8888 using this command:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8888 -j ACCEPT
```